# HTML5 Custom Video Player

Tags: html, video

I am developing a web app that will stream videos to a user, and the user will interact with the videos, for example recognize events on a specific timestamp, and then possibly store that in a database along with the video. I am going on with HTML5 because it is new, and compatible with tablets and smartphones. (iPad etc etc..). My question is that, does HTML5 offers this kind of customization ? or is it done only on Flash? And is there like a specific API Documentation about HTML5 video ?
(It will be all based on ruby on rails, but I don't see how that matters)

Comment: [The video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)

Comment: @EdS., [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). More importantly, [the real video element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-video-element).

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yeah, I remember reading that some time ago.  Fair enough, I w3schools just comes up first.

Comment: @EdS., You can [ban sites from your search results](https://www.google.com/reviews/t) which I've used for w3schools.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Not a bad idea.  I'm a systems guy who only rarely plays around with web shtuff, so I've never been burned by it.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibility’s to customize with [JavaScript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/). But I would recommend to use an [already made one](http://www.net-kit.com/20-html5-video-players/)